Computing the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{A^2+2 A B e^{C z}+B^2 e^{2Cz}-\beta^2}}$
Problem
I am attempting to compute the following antiderivative:
$$
I =\frac{A \sqrt{(A-\beta)(A+\beta)\left(C^2+K^2\right)}}{|K|} \int \frac{d z}{\sqrt{A^2+2 A B e^{C z}+B^2 e^{2Cz}-\beta^2}}
$$
—where, $A, B$ and $C$ are positively-valued constants, $\beta \in [-A, A]$, and where $K$ can take on any real value.
Here, $A$, $B$, and $C$ are positive constants, $\beta \in [-A, A]$, and $K$ can be any real number.
Using both manual methods and Mathematica, I derived the following elementary antiderivative (though it's rather complex):
$$
\frac{1}{2 C \sqrt{(A-\beta ) (A+\beta )}} \left(A \sqrt{\left(A-\beta +B e^{C z}\right) \left(A+\beta +B e^{C z}\right)} \sqrt{\frac{(A-\beta ) (A+\beta ) \left(C^2+K^2\right)}{K^2 \left(A-\beta +B e^{C z}\right) \left(A+\beta +B e^{C z}\right)}} \left(2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{A B e^{C z}}{A^2-\sqrt{(A-\beta ) (A+\beta )} \sqrt{\left(A-\beta +B e^{C z}\right) \left(A+\beta +B e^{C z}\right)}-\beta ^2}\right)+\log \left(-2 A^4-2 A^3 B e^{C z}+4 A^2 \beta ^2+2 A \beta ^2 B e^{C z}+2 ((A-\beta ) (A+\beta ))^{3/2} \sqrt{\left(A-\beta +B e^{C z}\right) \left(A+\beta +B e^{C z}\right)}-2 \beta ^4+\beta ^2 B^2 e^{2 C z}\right)-2 \log \left(e^{C z}\right)\right)\right)
$$
Unfortunately, while the integrand itself behaves nicely—being continuous and well-defined over $[-\infty, \infty]$ for all relevant values of $A$, $B$, $C$, $K$, and $\beta$—the antiderivative unexpectedly appears undefined in some regions. Moreover, when I compute the area using the antiderivative over a specific interval, the result is inconsistent with what I obtain from numerical integration, or even by estimating from a plot of the function.
Issues I’ve Encountered:

The antiderivative seems to break down or give undefined results for some values of $\beta$, likely due to terms inside the $\cosh^{-1}$ function becoming negative.
Numerical integration yields vastly different results compared to the antiderivative.
Simple visual estimates suggest that the numerical result is more plausible, as do comparisons to expected values obtained by considering the physical system this integral describes.


Edit: @Lai very kindly gave the following alternative result:
$$
\frac{A}{B C|K|} \sqrt{(A-\beta)(A+\beta)\left(C^2+K^2\right)} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{B e^{Cz}+A}{\beta}\right)+C
$$
Unfortunately, this result still disagrees with the result I obtain via numerical integration, and from the approximate expected value (which I can determine by examining the physical system which this integral represents).
Take, for example, the following Python script written to compare the two:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

# Example values
z1 = -500.7
z0 = -1000.4

A = 1.78
B = 0.454
C = 0.0132

theta = np.pi/2
beta = (A - B * np.exp(C * z0)) * np.cos(theta)
K = C * np.sqrt(A*2 - beta**2)/beta

# Analytical result due to @Lai
def integral_result(z):
        return (A / (B * C * np.abs(K))) * np.sqrt((A - beta) * (A + beta) * (C**2 + K**2)) * np.arccosh((B * np.exp(C * z) + A) / beta)

# The integrand
def integrand(z):
        return A*np.sqrt(((A - beta)*(A + beta)*(C**2 + K**2))/((K**2*(A**2 + 2*A*B*np.exp(C*z) + B**2*np.exp(2*C*z) - beta**2))))

result, error = quad(integrand, z0, z1)

print("Approximate Expected Value:", (z1 - z0))
print("Numerical Result:", result)
print("Analytical Result:", (integral_result(z1) - integral_result(z0)))

...which yields:
Approximate Expected Value: 499.7
Numerical Result: 686.6540420392445 Error: 2.7653177767412353e-08
Analytical Result: 0.03841463346517377

Note that I obtain similar results using other software, hence it is sadly very unlikely that the disparity is simply due to some software-related or numerical precision issue. The approximate expected value and the numerical/analytical results should be of the same order of magnitude.
Question
Where might my approach be going wrong? Could this be an issue with the elementary antiderivative or how I’ve structured the integral? How can I reconcile these results or find a more accurate method?
Any insights or alternative approaches to solving this integral would be greatly appreciated!

Is there some reason you haven’t factored out all those constants? Also, note the presence of $(A + Be^{Cz})^2$.

Let’s take out all constants first and rewrite the integral as
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{A \sqrt{(A-\beta)(A+\beta)\left(C^2+K^2\right)}}{|K|} \int \frac{d z}{\sqrt{A^2+2 A B e^{C z}+B^2 e^{2Cz}-\beta^2}} \\
& =M \int \frac{d z}{\sqrt{\left(B e^{C z}+A\right)^2-\beta^2}}, \textrm{ where }M= \frac{A \sqrt{(A-\beta)(A+\beta)\left(C^2+K^2\right)}}{|K|}
\end{aligned}
$$
Putting $Be^{Cz}+A=\beta \cosh \theta$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{M}{B C} \int \frac{\beta \sinh \theta d \theta}{\beta \sinh \theta} \\
& =\frac{M}{B C} \theta +C\\
& =\frac{M}{B C} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{B e^{Cz}+A}{\beta}\right)+C \\
& =\frac{A}{B C|K|} \sqrt{(A-\beta)(A+\beta)\left(C^2+K^2\right)} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{B e^{Cz}+A}{\beta}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.

Thank you @Lai.

Glad to know that the solution is helpful.

Thanks @Lai! This is a far simpler approach that what I'd been using. Unfortunately, however, using this to compute the integral over some interval still yields a result that differs significantly from what I obtain via numerical integration (and also what I obtain via visual examination of the plot of the integrand, or by considering the physical system which this integral represents). See the recent edit to my question. Do you have any insight here? Thanks a ton, again!

@IntegerEuler, could you confirm whether your actual integral part does or does not have a square root in the denominator. The title of the question suggests that it doesn’t, but much of the subsequent working says that it does. Either way, the solution above is incorrect when substituting for dz in terms of d.theta.

@lastchance My apologies for the confusion. Yes, there should be a square root in the denominator. The confusion resulted from some discussion surrounding how a previously posted form of the integrand in question should be simplified (I had originally posted the integrand $A\cdot\sqrt{\frac{(A-\beta)(A+\beta)(C^{2}+K^{2})}{K^{2}\left(A^{2}+2ABe^{Cz}+B^{2}e^{2Cz}-\beta^{2}\right)}}$). Thanks a ton for your help with this!

Try checking by simply back-differentiating.

@lastchance If I back-differentiate Lai's result, I get $\frac{e^{C z}}{\left(A+\beta +B e^{C z}\right) \sqrt{1-\frac{2 \beta }{A+\beta +B e^{C z}}}}$ (I've dropped the coefficient $M$ here). I don't believe this to be equivalent to the integrand, and Mathematica also tells me it isn't (although I've found that Mathematica sometimes errs in determining the equality of expressions).

I will add a solution to your post on the Stack Exchange [python] site shortly. (I'm currently at work). I don't think that Lai's solution is correct - the choice of substitution is OK, but its implementation is not.
